# Run nodejs static website

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to static web page generators and node js.  I have followed this link https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith.  I have successfully created and build a project using

```
wintersmith build
```

It has created a build folder and created some html files.   The problem is i have hosted this directly in IIS also and run it manully by opening the .html files in browser.  But it is not loading the proper page and when i click any hyper link on the page i am getting `404`  eventhough the pages are available.

I suspect that i have to run this in a server. But i am not sure how?

Comment: proper page  --> No CSS applied just a plain html i am getting

Comment: put downvote but leave a commemt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Install it via npm and simply run

```
http-server <path>
```

where  is the path to the folder where your `index.html` is located.

Comment: It worked, But my question is IIS also a Http server why it did not work there ?

Comment: Not sure, I guess it's a good idea to post your IIS configuration file also, and maybe what is the directory structure outputted by wintersmith.

Answer (score -2):

```
            ## Create folder public within it and create three file with the name home.html, contact.html, about.html
            ## After that create a page web.js

            var http = require('http');
            var fs = require('fs');
            http.createServer( function(request,response) {
                var url = request.url;
                switch(url) {
                case '/':
                getStaticFileContent(response,'public/home.html','text/html');
                break;
                case '/about':
                getStaticFileContent(response,'public/about.html', 'text/html');
                break;
                case '/contact':
                getStaticFileContent(response,'public/contact.html','text/html');
                break;
                default:
                response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                response.end('404-page not foud');
            }

            }).listen(4585);

            function getStaticFileContent(response, filepath, ContentType) {
                fs.readFile(filepath, function(error, data) {
                    if(error) {
                            response.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                            response.end('500- internal server Error');
                    } if(data) {
                        response.writeHead(200,{'ContentType':'text/html'});
                        response.end(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what your code does and how to use it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900831/create-website-with-node-js

Comment: So is this a question or an answer?

Comment: This is answer to how to create static website with Node.js